# Usando Mobx juntamente com o gerenciador de estado do StatFull em flutter é uma boa prática?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou em um projeto pessoal de Flutter + Dart usando pacote de gerenciador de estados Mobx. É um projeto bem grande onde a aplicação foi construída no modelo MVC.
A minha dúvida é eu posso usar o `setState` com o mobx? Algumas partes que uso `setState` é para mudar uma variável a partir de um click, normalmente variáveis de inicialização de telas. esse por exemplo é um componente:

```
import 'package:brucel_app/colors/mycolors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCardOnTap extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool visible;
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const MyCardOnTap({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.visible = false,
  });

  @override
  State<MyCardOnTap> createState() => _MyCardOnTapState();
}

class _MyCardOnTapState extends State<MyCardOnTap> {
  bool click = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool visible = widget.visible;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        setState(() {
          click = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() {
          click = false;
        });
      },
      onTapCancel: () {
        setState(() {
          click = false;
        });
      },
      onTap: widget.onPressed,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40, top: 40),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: click ? Mycolors.colorTextWhite : Mycolors.colorMain,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.label.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: widget.label.length > 30 ? 16 : 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: click ? Mycolors.colorTextDark : Mycolors.colorPrimary,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Visibility(
                visible: visible,
                child: const Icon(Icons.notifications_active_rounded,
                    color: Mycolors.colorPrimary))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Teoricamente você não precisa usar o setState quando se tem uma tela controlada pelo Mobx, pode ser que vc tenha algum processo que necessite que todos os componentes de tela seja carregado novamente, nesse caso você até pode usar o setState.

No seu exemplo, você pode definir a variável click como um observavel no seu controller do mobx.

@observable

bool click = false;

e então criar um método set para passar a informação sempre que aciona-lo.

void setClick(valor) => click = valor;

por fim os componentes de tela ficaria assim:

GestureDetector(
onTapDown: suaControllerMobx.setClick(true)
...

e o campo onde valida o click seria um Observer:

Observer(
builder: (_){
return Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40, top: 40),
margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: seuControllerMobx.click ? Mycolors.colorTextWhite : Mycolors.colorMain,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
),

}

você pode colocar esse trecho "seuControllerMobx.click ? Mycolors.colorTextWhite : Mycolors.colorMain," no controller do mobx como sendo um @computed assim e retornando apenas o resultado dele.